# Can not find div by class name with Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, selenium

Hey guys i'm trying to use selenium in order to automate some tasks.

And i'm trying to find this element:

```
class="sc-fubCfw irPtrP"
```

I'm using this method but it is not working:

```
button1 = driver.find_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sc-fubCfw irPtrP']"))
button1.click()
```

the code site is here:
[image]

Comment: The class name looks dynamic meaning it will change. Also check if it's under an iframe or shadow roots.

Comment: I tested sometimes and I realize that it's not dynamic. I will edit to add a photo with the code of rhe roots.

Comment: 1) is there a public url you can share? 2) Please don't post pictures of html. Use the snippet tool available in toolbar of [edit]

Comment: i'ts not a public url and i don't kow how to copy the code, 'cause of that a took a picture